# Crop custom shape from photo

Tags: java, android, path, imageview, android-canvas

I need to have an Android app with `ImageView` on the screen and user should be able to draw a custom (closed) shape (something like a circle/ellipse) made of curves to select an object on the image. The shape then has to be saved to `String` (like M123,21L23,30C100,29...). Does anybody know how to achieve this ? Or just point me the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage/blob/develop/src/com/android/camera/CropImage.java#L209)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to draw another bitmap on your `ImageView` and it shouldn't be dynamic, than use `AbsoluteLayout` and position them above each other.

If it should be much more dynamic, I recommend to use a **SurfaceView**. A tutorial can be found here: [Custome Shape from Photo](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html)

Comment: +1 for surfaceview suggestion. It sounds like that is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but I am more interested in how should I draw the closed curved shape and then save the shape to string representation.